# How to get the value of the text box outside foreach loop when I click the submit button?

Tags: php, foreach

I have a code like this: 
I want to know how to get the value of the textbox after i clicked the submit button because on my current code, it only gives me the last $key not all . Thanks

```
<form>
foreach($array as $key => $values){
echo "<input type='text' name='title' value='$key'/>";
}
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST[''])){
    //get the result of the textbox
    $title = $_POST['title'];

}
?>
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?  what are you writing same name for all input type ... you can also use array if you want to get value of multiple input type. why are you checking `isset($_POST[''])`  ?

Comment: you can just use `if(isset($_POST))` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want all the values use array notation, that is put an `[]` at the end of the element name and you get an array of values.

```
<form>
foreach($array as $key => $values){
echo "<input type='text' name='title[]' value='$key'/>";
}
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

...

```
<?php
    //get the result of the textbox
    $titles = $_POST['title'];
    foreach ($titles as $title){
        echo $title;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your testing for `if(isset($_POST[''])){` which will not help your situation. You need to do as follows.

```
if (isset($_POST['title')) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post">

<?php 
$array=array("a","b","c","d" );
foreach($array as $key => $values){
echo "<input type='text' name='title[]' value='$key'/>";
}
?> 

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/> 
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){ ECHO "<pre>"; print_r($_POST)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you should use the name as array

foreach($array as $key => $values){
echo "<input type='text' name='title[]' value='$key'/>";
}

<?php
    //result of the textbox
    $titles = $_POST['title'];
    print_r($titles);
?>
```